# Could not be converted to a type library - Error: Element not found

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, com

<sub>*NOTE: I am answering my own question in the event it helps others in the future.*</sub>

I'm getting the error:

> The assembly "C:\XYZ.dll" could not be converted to a type
>   library. Type library exporter encountered an error while processing
>   'XYZ'. Error: Element not found.

Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
[Guid("7a4e9867-96a7-43f0-9492-0327b9053853"),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class TimeSeriesPoint
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}

[Guid("7a4e9867-96a7-43f0-9492-0327b9053853"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IDataHelper
{
    //RCOMServerLib.IStatConnector Connector { set; }
    string Text { set; }
    void DoCallback();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was using the same GUID from the AssemblyInfo file:

```
[assembly: Guid("7a4e9867-96a7-43f0-9492-0327b9053853")]
```

You need to use unique GUIDs to resolve the error:

```
[Guid("C25D485B-F7DE-4F1C-99FE-FFAF5A219B77"),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class TimeSeriesPoint
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}

[Guid("FA6F70DD-CDD0-4FF3-94BA-E2B94E68321D"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IDataHelper
{
    //RCOMServerLib.IStatConnector Connector { set; }
    string Text { set; }
    void DoCallback();
```

To get unique GUIDs in Visual Studio click Tools Menu > Create GUID > select the 4th option **Registry Format** > Copy:

[image]

Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a440f695-652c-46d2-bb52-650c6227d3e9

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem, but with the final error statement:

```
Error: Error loading type library/DLL.
```

In my case, there was a referenced project/assembly that didn't have its `tlb` generated.

However, running `regasm` manually worked. It generated the `tlb` for both the referenced project/assembly and the target, `Acme.Widgets.dll`. And there were no explicit references to the related project specified on the `regasm` command line:

```
@ECHO OFF

pushd "%~dp0"

%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm Acme.Widgets.dll /tlb Acme.Widgets.tlb /codebase 

popd

pause
```

I eventually realized the referenced project/assembly didn't have the **Register for COM interop** setting enabled within Visual Studio. Figured it was enough to have it enabled for the target only, but that wasn't the case.

The referenced project/assembly began its life serving an ordinary .Net app where COM wasn't a factor.

Comment: Nice one, see comments in this answer, I think **Reg for Com Interop** should be more obvious when it's explicitly needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52050257/495455