# Excel VBA - runtime error 80004005 after server migration

Tags: excel, vba

Recently my company just performed a server migration and now one of my Excel VBA is not working,

Here's my code snippet:

```
Dim strSQL  As String, conStr As String
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

'On Error GoTo exitsub

Path = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Options").Cells(1, 6)
conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & Path & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
             
      
strSQL = "SELECT * From [MASTER]"
cnn.Open ConnectionString:=conStr 'stuck at this line
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
```

The place where I'm stuck at is when its trying to perform the `SELECT` query. The macro triggers when I save the file but doing so only give me this error:

[image]

I've checked my reference for Microsoft ActiveX Data Object, and confirmed that the latest one I have (16.0) is selected.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What path do you have in `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Options").Cells(1, 6)`?

Comment: thats the file path linking to this Excel document. Used to get the file in my connection string, `conStr` in the next line

Comment: This was obvious... Is it updated to the migrated server, with the correct workbook path? Of course, if the path has been changed.

Comment: yes. what i 1st did was change the server name to the migrated server. even clicked on the link (minus the excel file name) to confirm it took me to the correct file location.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Server-side automation of office is not supported https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

**Possible workaround**

Do it with .Net https://stackoverflow.com/a/52050257/495455

**Possible solution/workaround**

https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/107777?language=en_US

**Solution**

This is as designed behavior from Microsoft for the Excel driver which currently does not have feature to read from a password protected Excel file, unless it is open.

**Workaround**

Open the Excel file whose definition is being imported and provide the correct password and try to import the definition from Designer.